# React where to do mapping of api responses

Tags: reactjs, axios

This is more of a general question regarding the structure of a React application for which I could not find an answer. The following is my folder structure and is the one being used by an official React Material UI theme:

```
▼ src
  ▸ api
  ▸ components
  ▸ contexts
  ▸ hooks
  ▸ icons
  ▸ lib
  ▸ pages
  ▸ slices
  ▸ store
  ▸ theme
  ▸ types
  ▸ utils
```

I guess most of them are self-explanatory. However, there is one uncertainty that I am facing; the api calls. I am using the Axios library for api requests. Below is a sample from the `category.ts` inside the api folder:

```
import axios from '../lib/axios';

const endpoint = 'categories';

const readCategories = async () => axios.get<Array<Category>>(endpoint);
const postCategory = async (category: Category) => axios.post<Category>(endpoint, { params: category });
```

Most of the time the response api data has to be mapped to a different looking model. What is the recommendation here?

1. Mapping it straight in the component? Probably not that great as repetitive mapping has to be done in multiple components...
2. Transforming the data directly in the in the api layer, i.e. the `category.ts` file in my case? This would allow not to do any extra work in the component but different components might need different transformations.
3. In a seperate method which takes the api model as an input, transforms it to the model that is needed and then returns it?
4. Different suggestion...

Comment: I find a bit of contradiction within #1 and #2 . It all depends the data and the component which is consuming it . If the data is huge and its a transformation and if the transformed data need to be used in different components . Then we need to do transformation is the api layer itself before passing it to the components to consume it .

Comment: @Shyam well, if you are transforming it in the api layer and different components would expect different models, you would pass wrong models to some components. Yes, #1, #2 and #3 are contradictions. I am asking which would make the most sense

Comment: Maybe some middleware like [ReactQuery](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) ? You have same benefits like caching. You can think about GraphQl then you will get desired shape. If you use some state management like redux etc then you should store data in common (given by api shape) and transform to require in displaying it component.

Comment: That depends on the use case . This might sound like a typical answer :-) . But i think that's how it is . There is a thin line between good engineering and over engineering we can't write code in assumption on what might happen after 6 months . Building a product is a constant changing process IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You should create separate function in a separate file placed in Utils folder. This will Keep your component clean. The function can be re-used.

Comment: That's what I thought might be the best idea.